# Regex get ip between bracket and square bracket

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm kind of stuck in a regex situation.

I need to get an ip address that is between a bracket and square bracket.
This will get me the IP.

```
([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}
```

But if I do this, I also get the brackets.

```
\(\[([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}\]\)
```

I tried using a look ahead, but it does not work (I'm pretty sure its a syntax error, but I don't know how I would fix it).

```
\(\[(?=[([0-9]{1,3}[\.]){3}[0-9]{1,3})
```

This must work in Javascript.

Comment: There is no standard for regular expressions. You need to specify the tool that you are using to evaluate your regex. Is this JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use lookarounds.

```
(?<=\(\[)(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}(?=\]\))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eR0qB4/1)

**OR**

Since javascript won't support look-behinds , the only option we have is  [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and print the index 1 to get the ip-addresses.

```
\(\[((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\]\)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eR0qB4/2)

In javascript, it would be like

```
> var str = "foo ([122.122.122.122]) bar"
undefined
> console.log(/\(\[((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\]\)/.exec(str)[1]);
122.122.122.122
```

If the input contains more than one occurrences of addresses then use this,

```
> var str = "foo ([122.122.122.122]) bar foo ([122.122.122.122]) bar"
undefined
> var re = /\(\[((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})\]\)/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }
122.122.122.122
122.122.122.122
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but it also must work in JS, I forgot to add that in my OP. Look behinds do not work in JS.

Comment: here is a shorter regex var re = /\(\[((?:\d{1,3}\.?){4})\]\)/g;

Answer (score 0):

/([((?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3})])/g

[link to graphical description of this regular expression](http://jex.im/regulex/#!embed=false&flags=&re=%5C%28%5C[%28%28%3F%3A%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%29%7B3%7D%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%5C]%5C%29)

Comment: it is more a comment, it was put as an answer because of better formatting